# How to tell if a captured window is being displayed as retina in a retina display?

Tags: cocoa, retina-display

If i capture a window using something like...

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRectNull, kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow, windowID, kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming);
```

and say the window bounds was something like...

```
kCGWindowBounds = {
    Height = 150;
    Width = 490;
    X = 395;
    Y = 174;
};
```

If the window was on a retina display would the kCGWindowBounds height be reported as 300 or 150 but the resultant captured image be 300?

Thanks in advance, one of those things without at retina display I'm not sure about and think would be helpful for over developers too...

Answer (score 3):

Ok, found the answer by using Quartz-Debug to enable hidp modes, and dragged a window onto a screen with hidp enabled.

The answer is the height / width of the windows bounds is the same no matter if retina or not. But the captured image will be 2 times larger if being displayed on a retina screen.

I expected it to be the case but didnt want to make any assumptions.

Comment: The `bounds` 's unit is in `point`, not `pixel`, so it is the same on non-retina and retina. But the image size on disk, is always shown in pixel